# Element will close when you click a link or menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi i have a js element which is overlay and it pops up when i click my menu its providing me an overlay for it what im trying to do is when i click to a menu link it will close as well or when you click to any link it will close.

this is the code for it thank you so much im just new on js. the behavior is when im clicking the menu the menu shows up along with this when i click the link the overlay is still there

```
<script> 
 init=()=>{
        //SELECT & BIND (CLICK) EVENT
        document.querySelector('a.menuToggle, a#welcomeDivs').addEventListener('click',modal.overlay.init);
    }
    modal={
        overlay:{
            init:()=>{
                //CREATE OVERLAY 
                var overlay = document.createElement('overlay');
                overlay.id = 'welcomeDivsss';
                //SET (CLICK) EVENT TO REMOVE ITSLEF
                overlay.addEventListener('click',modal.overlay.remove);

                //APPEND TO INTERFACE
                document.body.appendChild(overlay);

                // After overlay added to html. "welcomeDivsss" is overlay id you specified.
                $( "#welcomeDivsss" ).append( '<div class="parela" id="welcomeDiv" <div class="inner_box"> <a id="#welcomeDivs" class="closes"></a> </div> </div>' );

            },
            remove:(e)=>{
                //REMOVE ITSELF
                e.target.parentNode.removeChild(e.target);
            }       
        }
    }

    //ON DOCUMENT LOAD RUN INIT
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',init);

</script>
```